# Stormpath (python) - get provider data

Tags: python, stormpath

I'm using stormpath-sdk-python with social authentication. After my user login - the api return the account information with `provider_data` attribute. But this is useless since its not accessible.

How can I access the provider data of the user?
I've been search a lot in the docs - but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've authenticated a user with social authentication, you can indeed access the provider data using... `provider_data` as a dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
print('Provider data: {}'.format(dict(provider_data)))
```